# Pathfinding - StackOverflowError

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, path-finding

I have a problem with pathfinding:

The start is at 0,0 and the finish as "C" at right bottom corner. It throws an `exeption java.lang.StackOverflowError` at

```
if(getPath(x, y+1)==true){ 
        return true;
    }
```

and

```
if(getPath(x, y-1)==true){ 
        return true;
    }
```

here is the method

```
public static boolean getPath(int x,int y, int num){


    if(x==startX-1|| y==startY-1 || x==endX+1 || y==endY+1){
        return false;
    }

    if (" C".equals(array[x][y])){
        return true;
    }

    if ("# ".equals(array[x][y])||"x".equals(array[x][y])){
        return false;
    }

    if ("[]".equals(array[x][y])){
        array[x][y]="+";
    }

    if(getPath(x, y+1,num)==true){ //vpravo
        return true;
    }

    if(getPath(x+1, y,num)==true){ //dolu
        return true;
    }
    if(getPath(x-1, y,num)==true){ //nahoru
        return true;
    }
    if(getPath(x, y-1,num)==true){ //vlevo
        return true;
    }

    if("+".equals(array[x][y])){
        array [x][y]="x";
    }

    return false; 

}


}
```

the values I use

```
public static Random r = new Random();
public static int i1 = r.nextInt(4) + 4;

public static int startX=0;
public static int startY=0;

public static int endX=i1-1;
public static int endY=i1-1;
public static int rows = i1;
public static int columns = i1;
public static String[][] array = new String[rows][columns];
```

I have i3-i14 for random obstacles they are defined so

```
public static int i3 = r.nextInt(4) ;
...
public static int i14 = r.nextInt(4) ;
```

After I changed the comparisons it stil throws the exeption

Edit:   I think I've found the problem.It's when the IF compare "+" and replaces it with "x"

```
if("+".equals(array[x][y])){
        array [x][y]="x";
```

could you help me with this? thanks

Comment: could you post test input data which you are using?

Comment: I'd recommend adding an additional parameter to `getPath`, `int num`. You could call `getPath` with `num` marked as zero, and whenever it is called recursively, call it using `num + 1`. At the start of your function, you could check to see if `num` has exceeded a certain number like ten iterations, then `return` from the call. 

This will allow you a safe method to debug with. Try using `System.out.println()` to print the values of `x` and `y` through iterations, and see how they match up with your logic.

Comment: @smajlo do you want the main too ?   btw I'm really thankfull for your help guys . I'm newbie in programing, I wanted to try this because it was interesting

Comment: I don't get how returning a boolean is finding a path? And what are the actual rules of the game? Somewhere you loop all the time as the == comparisons never return true. Use .equals to compare strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say with the given code, but three things come to mind:

1. Did you make sure to add C and all the other data?
2. Are those extra spaces around " C" and "# " supposed to be there?
3. Why did you convert `[]` to `+` and then to `x`? I'm guessing this is to mark that you've tried this cell, if so, can't you just set it to `x` before the 4 `getPath` calls? Setting it after the 4 calls means that you'll potentially just keep going in circles, thus the StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved the exeption . I put the comparisment between "+" and "x" before the getPath IFs and it works well

Answer (score 2):

For a start you need to use `.equals(.)` for String comparisons not `==`.

Try this old chestnut:

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

After that your logic to avoid re-tracing your steps might start working and you can avoid runaway recursion.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I changed the comparisons but it didn't solved the recursion overflow